# Workaround for negative lookbehind in Google Sheets

Tags: javascript, regex-lookarounds, google-sheets-query

I'm making a volunteers' self-scheduler using Google Sheets.  On one tab, the user enters a location and the time of their shift, formatted like so:

> NYC: 3/18/18, 11-2pm;  LA: 3/19/18, 7-8pm; HOME: 3/19/18, 8-10pm;
>   SANF: 3/20/18, 9-11AM;

and on another tab, I have made a table that reads that information and displays the volunteer's name and info under the corresponding cells for that scheduling shift and location.

```
=IFERROR(TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(CONCATENATE(ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({Shifts!$A$2:$A, Shifts!$B$2:$B, Vols!$C$2:$C, Vols!$D$2:$D, Vols!$G$2:$G}, "select Col1, Col2, Col4, Col5 where Col3 matches '.*(NYC: "&C$2&", "&C$3&").*'", 0) &"|")),"|",char(10))))
```

There's a row for every major location. In the query above, C$2 and C$3 are the date and time.  However, I would like to make a "misc" row to display volunteer shifts in locations that aren't common enough to have their own rows.  This row would exclude all the big locations.

I wrote a regex that almost expresses what I want, but unfortunately it appears that Google Sheets does not seem to support lookarounds yet.  Is there a reasonably concise way to recreate this without a lookbehind? I'm also happy to find a more elegant solution to the problem!

```
/.*(?<!NYC: |LA: |SANF:)3\/18\/18, 11-2pm.*/
```

Comment: Tried `/^(?!.*(NYC: |LA: |SANF:)3\/18\/18, 11-2pm).*3\/18\/18, 11-2pm/`?

Comment: Did anything work for you?